# How do I make sure a cron job completes?

Tags: cron

I only have access to cpanel and I have two different types of cron jobs that I would like to understand better:

This one seems to suffer time out constraints like a normal webpage does

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 -O /dev/null "https://www.website.com/code.php" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But what about this one?

```
php -q /home/website/public_html/code.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

How do I make sure a cron job completes?